# rollup-plugin-node-resolve not resolving dependency

Tags: rollupjs

This is going to be a pretty easy question, but after reading and rereading documentation, and a thousand different trials, I still cannot get my library to resolve my dependencies.

Directory hierarchy is :

```
root
 |-- package.json
 |-- rollup.config.js
 |-- node_modules
     |-- fast-json-patch
     |-- fp-rosetree
     |-- deep-equal
```

Rollup config file is :

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/transducer.umd.js',
    format: 'umd',
    name: 'StateTranducer',
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      module: true, // Default: true
      jsnext: false,  // Default: false
      main: true,  // Default: true
      browser: true,  // Default: false
      extensions: [ '.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json' ], 
      preferBuiltins: false,  // Default: true
      // Lock the module search in this path (like a chroot). Module defined
      // outside this path will be marked as external
      // jail: '/my/jail/path', // Default: '/'

      // Set to an array of strings and/or regexps to lock the module search
      // to modules that match at least one entry. Modules not matching any
      // entry will be marked as external
      only: [
        /^fp-rosetree$/,
      ], // Default: null
      modulesOnly: false, // Default: false
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: ['node_modules/**', "node_modules/deep-equal/**"],
    }),
    terser()
  ]
};
```

then my code has

```
import { applyPatch } from "fast-json-patch/"
```

The [`fast-json-patch`](https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch) library in its code features a `var _equals = require('deep-equal');`. In terminal, the error message I get is :

```
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
deep-equal (guessing 'deepEqual')
```

As the module [`deep-equal`](https://github.com/substack/node-deep-equal) can be found in `node_modules` directory, I expect rollup to be able to resolve it.  I even ran `npm install` in `node_modules/fast-json-patch` to install `deep-equal` in the `node_modules/fast-json-patch/node_modules` but that still failed to produce any result.

Note that `fp-rosetree` is correctly resolved, and fast-json-patch is a commonjs module, as you can guess from the rollup config.

What can I be missing?

Comment: did you find its solution?

Comment: nope, I just forked the package, and rewrote it with esm modules